# Eclipse Juno for Java EE doesn't have "Run as Java Application" on one Java SE class only

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-juno

I have what seems to be a weird problem with **Eclipse (Juno) for Java EE Developers**. One particular class that was created as Java SE GUI (extends JFrame) does not show "**Run as Java Application**" option.

So far I have tried the following to no avail:

- created another project and copied my java source file there
- created a new java class and copy-pasted my code into it

I also verified that I was in Java (not Java EE) view and that other java classes from older projects still have "Run as Java Application" option.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this situation?

Would it help if I post my code (it's rather small) here?

**UPDATE:**

That what actually was in the code:

```
public void  main() {
```

After I corrected it, the problem disappeared.

Comment: does it have a `main` method?

Comment: The code would help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class has to have a valid main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args){}

public static void main (String... args){}
```

Comment: **Thank you very much**. Somehow I managed to forget about `static` **and** about parameters (`String[] args`). Guess it was too late yesterday.  Shame on my anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the Run As... Java Application option is available on classes with a `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

Does that class define a `public static void main(String[] args)` method ?